# Get the difference between two strings without using arrays

Tags: php

I have two strings $A and $B sorted by integers. The implemented function must output {A - B} and {B - A} and the code must be WITHOUT ARRAYS. Any ideas?

Input:

```
$A = "1 2 3 8 9"; 
$B = "2 5 9 10 12 14";
```

Output:

```
{A - B} = "1 3 8"; 
{B - A} = "5 10 12 14";
```

Comment: You have to show us some of your code effort, so that we can correct that. Otherwise it seems that you asked us to do code for you.

Comment: You can use explode. array_diff(explode(" ", $A), eplode(" ", $B));

Comment: @TrueTiem: OP not want to use array

Comment: @devpro actually it's not array, still string. Only converting to array while using array_diff

Comment: **code must be WITHOUT ARRAYS** @TrueTiem

Comment: You can do this->https://3v4l.org/beQXC

Comment: @TrueTiem  it needs to be:- `implode(' ',(array_diff(explode(" ", $A), explode(" ", $B))));`

Comment: Walk throught the first string and for every found number (=surrounded by spaces or first/last char) try to find same number in the second string...

Comment: Sorry but the problem must be result without any array_* function

Comment: check this link https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.xdiff-string-diff.php

Comment: If you're going to ask us to solve your homework, you might as well copy/paste the entire question word-for-word so we know the exact requirements.

Comment: Sorry, is not homework, is a problem coding.

Comment: check @frzsombor answer

Answer (score 3):

```
$A = "1 2 3 8 9"; 
$B = "2 5 9 10 12 14";

//Build regular expression pattern from $A
$pattern = "/\b".str_replace(" ", "\b|\b", $A)."\b/";

//Remove matched numbers within word boundaries
$result = preg_replace($pattern, "", $B);

//Remove any unwanted whitespace
$result = trim(preg_replace("!\s+!", " ", $result));

echo "{B - A} = " . $result;
```

Comment: @eoitos I'm glad I could help! Please don't forget to accept my answer by clicking the checkmark to the left of it, if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use substring in a loop (and use the ASCII code) for each char to determine if they are equal or not and write them to an other string if they are not the same. If your digit is larger than 1 char you have to make the substring looking for the next space.

Comment: I thought that I could use the explode function

Comment: @eoitos the return value of `explode` is of what type …?

Comment: There are many different ways as mentioned in the comments and I also recommend use explode, but this function transforms a string into an array by your selected char. Your question was for an answere without arrays.

Comment: Exactly! Without array... Is no easy, I spend 3 days and i've not the solution

Answer (score 0):

Here's a looping version using [`strspn`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strspn.php) and [`substr`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) to extract numbers from the strings and [`substr_replace`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr-replace.php) to remove them when necessary:

```
$a = "1 2 3 8 9"; 
$b = "2 5 9 10 12 14";

$a_offset = 0;
$b_offset = 0;
while ($a_offset < strlen($a) && $b_offset < strlen($b)) {
    $a_length = strspn($a, '0123456789', $a_offset);
    $a_num = substr($a, $a_offset, $a_length);
    $b_length = strspn($b, '0123456789', $b_offset);
    $b_num = substr($b, $b_offset, $b_length);
    if ($a_num < $b_num) {
        // keep the a value
        $a_offset = $a_offset + $a_length + 1;
    }
    elseif ($b_num < $a_num) {
        // keep the b value
        $b_offset = $b_offset + $b_length + 1;
    }
    else {
        // values the same, remove them both
        $a = substr_replace($a, '', $a_offset, $a_length + 1);
        $b = substr_replace($b, '', $b_offset, $b_length + 1);
    }
}
echo "a - b = $a\nb - a = $b";
```

Output:

```
a - b = 1 3 8 
b - a = 5 10 12 14
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/O5BOO)